# Android N Preview emulator crash

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am getting this crash on the new Android N preview emulator, right on the start.

```
qemu: fatal: goldfish_tty_read: Bad offset 20
RAX=0000000000000009 RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=0000000000000000 RDX=0000000000000000
RSI=ffffffff817b6c7f RDI=ffff88005c3eb0c0 RBP=ffff88005e471bf8 RSP=ffff88005e471bb8
R8 =ffff88005c6a87f4 R9 =00000000ffffffff R10=ffff88005c3eb000 R11=0000000000000001
R12=ffffc9000003e000 R13=ffff88005e750810 R14=ffff88005c3eb000 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=ffffffff8127a837 RFL=00010246 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00000000
CS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00a09b00 DPL=0 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00000000
FS =0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00000000
GS =0000 ffffffff81a1f000 ffffffff 00000000
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00000000
TR =0040 ffffffff81a1a8c0 00002087 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     ffffffff81a09000 0000007f
IDT=     ffffffffff579000 00000fff
CR0=8005003b CR2=000000000040f6d0 CR3=000000005c2a8000 CR4=000006b0
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000044 CCD=0000000000000000 CCO=EFLAGS  
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 FPR1=0000000000000000
FPR2=0000000000000000 FPR3=0000000000000000
FPR4=0000000000000000 FPR5=0000000000000000
FPR6=0000000000000000 FPR7=0000000000000000
XMM00=ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00 XMM01=00000000000000000000000000000031
XMM02=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM03=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM04=65675f6f7364765f5f00757063746567 XMM05=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM06=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM07=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM08=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM09=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM10=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM11=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM12=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM13=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM14=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM15=00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Any thoughts how to fix this?

I am on Mac OS X - El capitan.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue today. Managed to fix it by changing emulator's ABI from **x86_64** to **x86**. Create new Virtual Device and on System Images list select the image with **x86** ABI (Download it if you don't have it already). Hope it helps.