# Android studio emulator not running: cannot find kernel-ranchu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have been trying to get the emulator from android studio running but have consistently failed. At first, it complained about missing ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, but when I set it, create an emulator with the latest x86 or x86_64 images with google apis, I get the following error:

```
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (/mnt/hdd/.android) but cannot find kernel file in /mnt/hdd/.android/system-images/ sub directories
```

The AVD itself is created under `~/.android/avd/` even though my sdk root is defined in both env *and* android studio as `/mnt/hdd/.android`. I have confirmed that both `system.img` and `kernel-ranchu` and other files exist under `/mnt/hdd/.android/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86{,_64}/`.

I have tried to run the emulator from the commandline, which seems to work fine only with an x86 image (it crashes with x86_64, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904110/android-n-preview-emulator-crash)).

```
$ ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/mnt/hdd/.android emulator -datadir /mnt/hdd/.android -avd nougat_25
```

So, I suspect the issue with avd manager might be that -datadir is messed up when trying to run the emulator from android studio's avd manager.

How can I add the `-datadir` flag to the avd manager so that I can run the emulator properly from avd manager. It is cumbersome to reinstall a new apk every time I change the code and try to test it, and I don't want to have to keep reinstalling the app on my phone as I don't have a spare yet.

If adding the flag is not an option, how else can I go about fixing the above issue with avd manager's emulator?

EDIT: I was able to make it work by renaming `emulator` to `emulator-real` in `/mnt/hdd/.android/tools/`, creating a file called `emulator` in the same directory with the following contents. Setting the exec bit on the file seems to fool android studio into running my own script.

```
#!/bin/sh

export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/mnt/hdd
/mnt/hdd/.android/tools/emulator-real -datadir /mnt/hdd/.android -kernel /mnt/hdd/.android/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/kernel-ranchu -system /mnt/hdd/.android/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/system.img -ramdisk /mnt/hdd/.android/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/ramdisk.img -initdata /mnt/hdd/.android/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/userdata.img "$@"
```

Essentially this means setting `-kernel` `-system` `-initdata` and `-ramdisk` options separately so the emulator can pick up the right files.

I would still like to know of a better way to fix this issue as replacing `emulator` with a proxy script is hacky and the script has to be changed every time I make a new emulation profile.